# Applying rotation to GLSurfaceView

Tags: android, android-camera2, glsurfaceview

I am attempting to use a GLSurfaceView to render output from Camera2. It works OK when the device is in portrait mode, however when rotating to landscape, of course the picture is "sideways".

I've done a bit of looking around as to how to apply rotation to the output, however there seems to be a multitude of different ways, and I was hoping there would be a simple one that would fit into mine.

This is an abridged version of my GLSurfaceView descendant:

```
public class DWGLCameraView extends GLSurfaceView implements Renderer, OnFrameAvailableListener {
    
    // Other parts snipped

    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {

        mSurfaceTexture.updateTexImage();
        float[] mtx = new float[16];
        mSurfaceTexture.getTransformMatrix(mtx);

        // Can I do something here to apply the rotation?

        mDrawer.draw(mtx);

    }  
}
```

..and this (if it helps), is the <s>draw routine</s> DWGLDrawer class:

```
import android.opengl.GLES11Ext;
import android.opengl.GLES20;
import android.opengl.Matrix;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;
import java.nio.ShortBuffer;

public class DWGLDrawer {

    private final String vertexShaderCode =
            "attribute vec4 vPosition;" +
            "attribute vec4 inputTextureCoordinate;" +
            "uniform mat4 u_xform;\n" +
            "varying vec2 textureCoordinate;" +
            "void main()" +
            "{"+
                "gl_Position = vPosition;"+
                "textureCoordinate = (u_xform * inputTextureCoordinate).xy;" +
            "}";

    private final String fragmentShaderCode =
            "#extension GL_OES_EGL_image_external : require\n"+
            "precision mediump float;" +
            "varying vec2 textureCoordinate;\n" +
            "uniform samplerExternalOES s_texture;\n" +
            "void main() {" +
            "  gl_FragColor = texture2D( s_texture, textureCoordinate );\n" +
            "}";

    private FloatBuffer vertexBuffer, textureVerticesBuffer;
    private ShortBuffer drawListBuffer;
    private final int mProgram;
    private int mPositionHandle;
    private int mTextureCoordHandle;

    private short drawOrder[] = { 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3 }; // order to draw vertices

    // number of coordinates per vertex in this array
    private static final int COORDS_PER_VERTEX = 2;

    private final int vertexStride = COORDS_PER_VERTEX * 4; // 4 bytes per vertex

    private static float squareCoords[] = {
       -1.0f,  1.0f,
       -1.0f, -1.0f,
        1.0f, -1.0f,
        1.0f,  1.0f,
    };

    private static float textureVertices[] = {
        0.0f, 1.0f,
        0.0f, 0.0f,
        1.0f, 0.0f,
        1.0f, 1.0f,
    };

    private int texture;
    private int mTransformLocation;

    public DWGLDrawer(int texture) {
        this.texture = texture;
        // initialize vertex byte buffer for shape coordinates
        ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(squareCoords.length * 4);
        bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        vertexBuffer = bb.asFloatBuffer();
        vertexBuffer.put(squareCoords);
        vertexBuffer.position(0);

        // initialize byte buffer for the draw list
        ByteBuffer dlb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(drawOrder.length * 2);
        dlb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        drawListBuffer = dlb.asShortBuffer();
        drawListBuffer.put(drawOrder);
        drawListBuffer.position(0);

        ByteBuffer bb2 = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(textureVertices.length * 4);
        bb2.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        textureVerticesBuffer = bb2.asFloatBuffer();
        textureVerticesBuffer.put(textureVertices);
        textureVerticesBuffer.position(0);

        int vertexShader    = loadShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vertexShaderCode);
        int fragmentShader  = loadShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentShaderCode);

        mProgram = GLES20.glCreateProgram();             // create empty OpenGL ES Program
        GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, vertexShader);   // add the vertex shader to program
        GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, fragmentShader); // add the fragment shader to program
        GLES20.glLinkProgram(mProgram);                  // creates OpenGL ES program executables
    
        mTransformLocation = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "u_xform");
    }

    public void draw(float[] mtx) {
        GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgram);

        GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, texture);

        GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mTransformLocation, 1, false, mtx, 0);
        
        // get handle to vertex shader's vPosition member
        int positionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "vPosition");

        // Enable a handle to the triangle vertices
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(positionHandle);

        // Prepare the <insert shape here> coordinate data
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(positionHandle, COORDS_PER_VERTEX, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, vertexStride, vertexBuffer);

        int textureCoordHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "inputTextureCoordinate");
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(textureCoordHandle);
        
//        textureVerticesBuffer.clear();
//        textureVerticesBuffer.put( transformTextureCoordinates( textureVertices, mtx ));
//        textureVerticesBuffer.position(0);
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(textureCoordHandle, COORDS_PER_VERTEX, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, vertexStride, textureVerticesBuffer);

        GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, drawOrder.length, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, drawListBuffer);

        // Disable vertex array
        GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(positionHandle);
        GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(textureCoordHandle);
    }
    
    private int loadShader(int type, String shaderCode) {

        // create a vertex shader type (GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER)
        // or a fragment shader type (GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER)
        int shader = GLES20.glCreateShader(type);

        // add the source code to the shader and compile it
        GLES20.glShaderSource(shader, shaderCode);
        GLES20.glCompileShader(shader);

        return shader;
    }

    private float[] transformTextureCoordinates( float[] coords, float[] matrix) {          
       float[] result = new float[ coords.length ];        
       float[] vt = new float[4];      

       for ( int i = 0 ; i < coords.length ; i += 2 ) {
           float[] v = { coords[i], coords[i+1], 0 , 1  };
           Matrix.multiplyMV(vt, 0, matrix, 0, v, 0);
           result[i] = vt[0];
           result[i+1] = vt[1];
       }
       return result;
    }
}
```

As per my comment in `onDrawFrame`, I figured that I might be able to apply rotation there. I had tried this:

```
if (mRotation > 0)
  Matrix.rotateM(mtx, 0, mRotation, 0f, 0f, -1f);
```

(mRotation is the rotation value in degrees)

however that resulted in an unintelligible picture, so I assume that it's completely wrong, or there's something else I need to do

Please remember that I am using Camera2, so `setDisplayOrientation` (from Camera) is not an option

**EDIT**

I've now included the entire declaration for DWGLDrawer, and added to the description

Comment: Your untangible image probably is because you have rotated one of the axis (x, y, or z), maybe this should work ```Matrix.rotateM(mtx, 0, mRotation, 1f, 1f, 0f);```

Answer (score 0):

In general, your approach should be correct (assuming mRotation is in degrees and is based on something like [Display.getRotation()](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/view/Display?hl=en#getrotation) to determine your UI orientation - note that getRotation doesn't return degrees so the value has to be adjusted).

However, you don't have your shader code here, so it's hard to say if you're using mTransformLocation in a way that's compatible with the rotateM call you use. So probably you just need to debug the values you see for the matrix, what the rotate call does, and so on, to figure out where the math goes haywire.  Unfortunately common for dealing with transforms in EGL (or anywhere, really).

Comment: Oops! I was passing the getRotation value, rather than the actual value in degrees. I've now updated the question to include the entire DWGLDrawer class, in case that helps